# How can I pass $_SESSION credentials in a href to access a specific HTML page?

Tags: php, html, session

I need to pass from php (ValidationLogin.php) some variables (email, password and ID) in the href of a , to access a HTML page that is specific for the logged in user. Can you tell me guys how to pass this variables into my href? Do not worry about SQL-Injection i'll fix it later...

**CODE: ValidationLogin:** (I pass my email and password into a session to use it afterwords)

```
<?php
// connect to the database
$db = new mysqli('', '', '', ''); //This is normaly filled and not empty

if ($db->connect_error) 
{
    die("Connection failed: " . $db->connect_error);
}


$arr = array();

$Email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$Passwd = $_REQUEST['passwd'];


$Query = "SELECT Passwd FROM place WHERE Email = '$Email'";
$DBResult = mysqli_query($db, $Query);
$DB_Hashed_Passwd = mysqli_fetch_assoc($DBResult);
$Hashed_Passwd = $DB_Hashed_Passwd["Passwd"];

if (password_verify($Passwd, $Hashed_Passwd)) 
{   
    $Query = "SELECT Id, Firstname FROM place WHERE Email = '$Email'";
    $DBResult = mysqli_query($db, $Query);
    $Place = mysqli_fetch_assoc($DBResult);

    array_push($arr,$Place["Id"]);
    array_push($arr,$Place["Firstname"]);

    session_start();
    $_SESSION['email'] = $Email;
    $_SESSION['passwd'] = $Passwd;

    echo json_encode($arr);
} 
else
{
    echo json_encode(null);
}

mysqli_close($db);  
   ?>
```

**index.php:** (on this page i've a button that redirects me to a specific page so i need to pass email and password in the href --> this credentials are active into the session but i don't know how to pass them into the href):

```
<?php

    $email = $_SESSION['email'];
    $passwd = $_SESSION['passwd'];

    if(isset($_SESSION['email']))
    {
        echo '<a href="./DisplayDrink.php?email=$email&passwd=$passwd"><button><i class="fa fa-edit"></i>&nbsp; Manage My Drinks</button></a>';
    }

?>
```

Could someone tell me how to fix it or tell me something better?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Session vars should be available and you don't have to pass them as parameters.

Just `session_start();` should be called before checking them:

```
<?php

    session_start();
    $email = $_SESSION['email'];
    $passwd = $_SESSION['passwd'];

    if(isset($_SESSION['email'])) {
        echo '<a href="./DisplayDrink.php?email=$email&passwd=$passwd"><button><i class="fa fa-edit"></i>&nbsp; Manage My Drinks</button></a>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. When i pass the code like this whith the session_start, and also email=$email and passwd=$passwd, it doesn't pass the credentials in the URL. The variables $email and $passwd are seen as string in the URL and not as the credentials of the logeed user...

Comment: in your link it doesn't work because the string is between single quotes, all vars between single quotes don't get processed, what you can do is close the string and concatenate the values: `echo '<a href="./DisplayDrink.php?email='.$email.'&passwd='.$passwd.'"><button><i class="fa fa-edit"></i>&nbsp; Manage My Drinks</button></a>'; Or use double quotes around the whole string and then escape all double quotes inside it, but I prefer the other option of using concatenation here, it seems cleaner.

Comment: Thanks man! It works fine with the first option! Thanks a lot!